# Converting String in Array with the same Characters

Tags: ruby, string, split

I have a String like this in Ruby: `"33255563"`

Is it possible to create an Array like this: `["33", "2", "555", "6", "3"]` ?

Comment: What is the code you are having trouble with? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ? Please, provide a [mre]. Please be aware that [so] is not a code-writing service, you need to show your efforts!

Comment: "Yes/No" type questions don't make good questions on [so], since the answer is either Yes or No. "Is it possible" questions are particularly bad questions on [so], because a) pretty much everything is possible, so the answer is almost always "Yes, you just have to write a program which does that", and b) the only possible answers are "Yes" and "No", and neither improves the knowledge of the software development community, which is what [so] is about. The purpose of [so] is to build a repository of knowledge that cannot be found elsewhere, and *good* questions invite answers that do just that.

Comment: As you can see, my reputation on Stack Overflow is very low, so it is my first steps in this platform. I did not know that I need to tell the whole background to ask something I do not know if it is possible or not. Talking about the language itself (Ruby), I started to use this language last month, so basically it is my first contact with the language and, if the answers was just the methods, I would be very thankful too. If the question breaks some rules of the platform, please let me know and i'll remove it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
s.each_char.chunk_while(&:==).map(&:join)
 => ["33", "2", "555", "6", "3"]
```

Comment: my pleasure man

Comment: Tried and ti works, thank you :)

Comment: @CarySwoveland you saved me the effort. You know how much I abhor intermediaries :)

Answer (score 2):

Input

```
a="33255563"
```

Program

```
p a.chars.slice_when{|a,b|a!=b}.map(&:join)
```

Output

```
["33", "2", "555", "6", "3"]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
str = "33255563"
```

```
str.gsub(/(.)\1*/).to_a
  #=> ["33", "2", "555", "6", "3"]
```

This uses [String#gsub](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/String.html#method-i-gsub) with one argument and no block, which returns an enumerator. This form of `gsub` performs no substitutions; it merely generates matches of the given pattern, which here is a regular expression.

We can write the regular expression in *free-spacing* mode to make it self-documenting.

```
/
(.)   # match any character and save to capture group 1
\1*   # match the content of capture group 1 zero or more times,
      # as many as possible
/x    # invoke free-spacing regex definition mode
```

Note that [String#scan](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/String.html#method-i-scan) cannot be used because the regular expression contains a capture group.